# Docker, Nginx and PHP7: ERROR 111 Connection refused while connecting to upstream

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose, nginx-location

I run a NGINX-PHP7-COMPOSER image that works well but when using Slim Framework I had to change Nginx's default config to make the URL rewrites work.

And now it show this error in the logs:

> 2017-01-21 14:38:34,357 INFO success: php-fpm7 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
>
> 2017-01-21 14:38:34,359 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
>
> 2017/01/21 14:38:37 [error] 15#15: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: auth-api, request: "GET /hello HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.6:9000", host: "localhost:9100"
>
> 172.18.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2017:14:38:37 +0000] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 502 537 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"

The config file I mounted is loaded (I checked the bash with nginx -T):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name auth-api;
    index index.php;
    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass auth-api:9000;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

My Dockerfile (just the image i am loading from the repository):

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm
```

And my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:

#############
## MARIADB ##
#############

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - "./log/mariadb:/var/log/mysql:rw"
            - "./data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"

##############
## FRONTEND ##
##############

    frontend:
        image: skiychan/nginx-php7:latest
        volumes:
            - ./services/frontend/src:/data/www
        links:
            - mariadb:mysql
        ports:
            - "9001:80"

##############
## AUTH API ##
##############

    auth-api:
        build: ./services/api/auth/
        volumes:
            - ./services/api/auth/code/:/var/www/html
            - ./services/api/auth/:/etc/nginx/sites-available/
        links:
            - mariadb:mysql
        ports:
            - "9100:80"
            - "9000:9000"
```

Do you have any idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: So, did you actually check that your server 172.18.0.6 indeed responds at port 9000/tcp? Does that host have any firewall rules that may forbid client 172.18.0.1 to connect to port 9000/tcp? Did you actually try to connect from this client machine to that server using common troubleshooting tools like `telnet`? Did you try running `tcpdump` on server to monitor whether client's request really gets to server?

Comment: By the way, how is this question related to programming? Perhaps you may have better luck asking at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).